# How to make the first word of DateComponentsFormatter.string(from:)'s result capitalised?

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, dateformatter

In my iOS project I have a function to convert an integer value to string with the "seconds" postfix:

```
func secondsToString(_ seconds: Int) -> String {    
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .full
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.second]
    return formatter.string(from: DateComponents(second: seconds)) ?? ""
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
print(secondsToString(10)) // Output is "10 seconds"
print(secondsToString(1)) // Output is "1 second"
```

However I need to make the first word of `secondsToString`'s result capitalised, like that:

```
print(secondsToString(10)) // Output is "10 Seconds"
print(secondsToString(1)) // Output is "1 Second"
```

How can I solve this problem? Should I change some property of `DateComponentsFormatter`?

Comment: since formatter.string(from: DateComponents(second: seconds)) returns a string you can add . capitalized keyword to it to return it exactly how you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.capitalized` at the end of your formatted string.

```
func secondsToString(_ seconds: Int) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .full
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.second]
    return formatter.string(from: DateComponents(second: seconds))?.capitalized ?? ""
}
```

**Note:** This solution will capitalize all words that are returned from the method. For your use case this should be good enough, because even if you add more time units, if i were capitalizing one, i would prefer capitalizing all of them.

---

So, if you were to change the result in some way and want only the first word to be capitalized, you could try this: (First word means first word which contains a letter)

```
func secondsToString(_ seconds: Int) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .full
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .hour, .day]
    let string = formatter.string(from: DateComponents(second: seconds)) ?? ""
    var substrings = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
    // Using for...each would make the iterating element a constant and hence i would have to find the index and replace it using the index
    for i in 0...substrings.count {     
        if let firstCharacter = substrings[i].unicodeScalars.first, CharacterSet.letters.contains(firstCharacter) {
            substrings[i] = substrings[i].capitalized
            break
        }
    }
    let finalString = substrings.joined(separator: " ")
    return finalString
}
```

Comment: By the way, `capitalized` will capitalize all words, not just the first one.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, i am aware. This is a simple solution for OP’s code snippet. Even otherwise, if the method returns more time units, i think he would prefer to capitalize them as well.

Comment: The question title is "how to make the first word of..." :)

Comment: @Sulthan Currently this is the best solution, but you are right, it does not search for the first word in `DateComponentsFormatter.formatter.string(from:)`.

Comment: @Sulthan i have added a really ugly solution. Please suggest improvements if any, or if you have a better answer please post it so that we could all learn.

Comment: @RomanPodymov updated the answer if you need that specific case.